# Encoding ship data with AIS

Tags: ais

How to encode Vessel data (position, course, speed & ect.) with AIS (Automatic Information System) AIVDM/AIVDO sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a php version for encoding at my repo [here - phpais](https://github.com/ais-one/phpais)

It should be pretty straight forward to understand the code if you understand how AIS strings are composed

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question it depends on which AIS message you want to send? (See the second link for the different msg.)

As you might see, it is a rather complexed task, but basically you have to do what is done here [it-digin.com](http://www.it-digin.com/blog/?p=20) in reversed order. But there are several different message types, you can read more about the standard here [United States Coast Guard](http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=AISMessagesA)

Comment: In   order to reverse the algorithm in [AIS message manual decoding](http://www.it-digin.com/blog/?p=20) (the 1st link above) you need to know which charecters are permissible. It seems they are '0'..'W' and '`', 'a'..'w'. ('xyzXYZ' are not included!). [AIS NMEA encoding/decoding](https://softwaredevelopmentperestroika.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/more-fun-with-python-navigational-tricks-ais-nmea-encodingdecoding/) may be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ais2csv ? It works well with NMEA sentences
https://github.com/dma-ais/AisLib/tree/master/ais-lib-cli/launch4j/ais2csv